# Can I create a walled garden allowing only my organisation's users to use my ejabberd instance

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Can I create a walled garden allowing only my organisation's users/ clients to use my ejabberd instance/ service.

This includes registration of users done only by my backend and preventing other clients' users to register or access the server. Additionally users of another server can not be added by existing users.

Answer (score 0):

> This includes registration of users done only by my backend

Then probably limit mod_register using the options access_from and ip_access:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/configuration/modules/#mod-register

And then write your custom web application that sends ReST or XMP-RPC queries to ejabberd's
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/#understanding-ejabberd-commands

and executes the "register" API command:
https://docs.ejabberd.im/developer/ejabberd-api/admin-api/#register

> and preventing other clients' users to register

If you use your custom web to show a formulary, that's your duty.

> or access the server.
> Additionally users of another server can not be added by existing users.

You may want to disable S2S (server-to-server), so communication from/to your XMPP server to other XMPP servers is not allowed.

Comment: Thanks. Will try. Didn't understand this -> If you use your custom web to show a formulary, that's your duty. Could you please explain

Comment: I mean that, depending on what method you allow your users to register accounts, there's where you will limit their ability to register  them. mod_register (and mod_register_web) has ip_access. In this sense, it's obvious that, if you write a web page, then that page should be accessible only from the desired IP addresses.

Comment: Third alternative: if you have few users, disable account registration at all. Only admins will register accounts, manually, on demand. In that case, configure mod_register to allow password change.